# Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(1+u(x))^{v(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}u(x)\cdot v(x)}$ if $u(x)\rightarrow 0$ and $v(x)\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, proof-explanation

My study book gives out the following equation as a rule, but without any further explanation. I don't know where to start, as my knowledge of limits and exponentials is quite limited.
$$(u(x)\rightarrow 0) \wedge (v(x) \rightarrow \infty) \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a}(1+u(x))^{v(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}u(x)\cdot v(x)}$$
I'm interested in its proof, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
(1+u(x))^{v(x)}=\left[(1+u(x))^{1/u(x)}\right]^{u(x)v(x)}.
$$
Then,
\begin{gather}
\lim_{x\to a}(1+u(x))^{1/u(x)}=\lim_{z\to 0}(1+z)^{1/z}=e,\\\lim_{x\to a}u(x)v(x)\text{ exists (the question assumes this implicitly)}
\end{gather}
and the result you seek follows.

Comment: Are you claiming that $\lim_{x\to a}u(x)v(x)$ exists? If $u(x)=x$,$v(x)=1/x^2$ and $a=0$ then the limit  does not exist?

Comment: @K.Power I don't assume $\lim_{x\to a}u(x)v(x)$ exists. I think the question assumes it implicitly.

Comment: Ok I was just clarifying, wasn't sure what its presence in your OP suggested. Thanks for clarifying in the post, have my +1.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need the hypothesis  $$\lim_{x\to a}v(x)=+\infty.$$

we only need

$$\lim_{x\to a}v(x)\left(\ln(1+u(x))-u(x)\right)=0$$

to have

$$e^{v(x)\ln(1+u(x))}\sim e^{u(x)v(x)}\;(x\to a)$$